# UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions not compiling with 4.3 SDK (fine with 4.2 SDK)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4

I've been compiling and using the following code since iOS 4.0:

```
if(UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL)
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(drawCopyFS.frame.size, NO, 0.0);
} 
else 
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawCopyFS.frame.size);
}
```

As soon as I switched to 4.3 SDK, this particular piece of code stopped compiling with the following two errors:

- `'UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions' undeclared  (error on line #1)`
- `Implicit declaration of function 'UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions' (error on line #7)`

Anyone have any ideas why this is happening? Is something changed in 4.3, or how can I fix this?

Xcode doesn't color `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` the same way as it does `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` and at the same time it doesn't provide any quick help for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure the Base SDK is set to use the latest in the Project Info.  If that doesn't work then read on.

I had a similar problem with UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier which was introduced in 4.0 and compiled fine before the SDK update.  It turned out that Xcode was attempting to use headers from the iOS 3.2 SDK. The console output of the build process showed the old headers search path was passed into the compiler even though the Base SDK was most definitely set to the lastest in the Project Info.

Reloading the project didn't help.  Restarting Xcode had no effect.  There are reports that manually editing the project file has been necessary with past updates.  However, when I opened the project file in a text editor I found the SDKROOT variables were correctly set to the latest SDK path.

What worked in my case was closing Xcode, restoring the 'MyProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj'  file from source control to a point just prior to updating the SDK, then restarting Xcode and opening the project.

Comment: VERY interesting. I've changed the Base SDK setting from "Latest iOS (iOS 4.3)" to "iOS 4.3" and the code compiled fine. Then I changed it back to "Latest iOS (iOS 4.3)" and it kept compiling just fine. Hmm ... looks like some sort of an Xcode gremlin needed to be punted away. Thanks!

Comment: Forgot to mention I tried that too but it didn't work in my case.  I wish I'd kept a copy of the bad project file for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with that symbol and also a bunch of other symbols, selectors and macros. As with the other responder, cleaning everything and removing pre-compiled headers didn't fix it. Nor did changing the SDK. What did fix it is switching from a simulator build to a device build, and then switching back.

Comment: interesting, thanks for sharing. these kind of bugs are really annoying. hard to tell what is really going on here.